# Div with 100% width inside a centered div with dynamic width?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, width, center

I'm not sure how to make this work crossbrowser-wise, so I need some of your expertise ;)

How do I make styling that looks like this and works crossbrowser-wise? (IE7 as well)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/examplek.jpg/

- The red box has a fast defined width
- The green box is centered inside the red box and has a dynamic width + a padding/border
- The blue box is a "mouseover" div which needs to have the same width as the green box (without the padding/border)

Comment: Would prefer a CSS method, if JS can be avoided for this..

Comment: The only reason i included some JS was to give the wrapper a random width, to demonstrate that dynamic width would be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this (with a dynamic width for green box):  **http://jsfiddle.net/nKdt6/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>
            lorem ipsum
        <p>
        <div>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p>      
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    background-color : red;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
}

.inner {
    background-color: lime;
    border: 3px black solid;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;        
}

.inner > div {
    display: none;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;  
}

.inner:hover > div {
    display: block;   
}
```

To center the .`inner` element when it has a dynamic width we can use `text-align: center` in `.outer` and `display: inline-block` in `.inner`. I have added the extra CSS `*display: inline` and `*zoom: 1` to make this work in IE7 as it does not support `display: inline-block`.

#### Edit

To get a thin black outline (outer border) around a wide white inner boder (as achieved and demonstrated by @DonPedro in the comments below), you can add a second border to an inner child element that controls the full height and width of the parent element. In the example above, this is `.inner > p`.

**CSS**

```
.inner {
    ...
    border: 1px black solid; 
    ...
}

.inner > p {
    ...
    border: 10px solid white;
    ...
}
```

**Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nKdt6/1/** (provided by @DonPedro)

This cannot be achieved using `outline` due to the `border-radius` styling, and as far as I am aware Mozilla is the only browser that supports any type of outline radius (`-moz-outline-radius`).

Comment: `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1` is how you make `inline-block` work in IE7.

Comment: @DonPedro You can change the border thickness / color within `.inner` by changing `border: 3px black solid;` to how you want it. You can also change the padding in there as well. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. Instead, changing left + right attributes to the given padding/border did the trick :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DonPedro Ok, if you would like to edit my answer with the changes you made then I will review them and accept the edit if it isn't localised.

Comment: Sure thing, hopefully other can benefit from it as well - I added the changes in here: http://jsfiddle.net/nKdt6/1/

Comment: @DonPedro I'm sure it will so I have added that information to my answer